# Editing a wordpress theme

Tags: css

I'm trying to edit a wordpress theme. 
Here's the website: http://findbeauty.be

I'm having a problem where I can't find the parts in the code that I need to edit. In the nav bar you can see the 'white triangles' that cut a part from the black nav bar.

I've looked everywhere in the CSS and I can't find it. Is there any way other than CSS where you would be able to get such an end result? In php or so? Where would I have to look?

If I use Firebug to locate the element I get this:

```
<nav class="nav" role="navigation">
```

Full stylesheet added below. Thanks!

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {

  /* Overall */
  .container {
    margin: 10px auto; 
    width: 90%; 
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .header {
    position: relative; 
    width: 90%; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
    padding: 40px 0 0 0;
  }
  .section {
    clear: both; 
    margin: 20px 0;
  }
  .aside {
    clear: both; 
    margin: 30px 0; 
    background: #f8f8f8;
  }
  .footer {
    clear: both; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
    width: 100%; 
    color: #777;
  }

  /* .header form */
  .header-form {
    display: none;
  }

  /* .nav */
  .mobile-nav {
    display: block; 
    width: 100%; 
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .nav {
    position: relative; 
    width: 96%; 
    background: #000; 
    display: inline-block; 
    padding: 2%; 
    margin-top: 40px; 
    clear: both; 
    line-height: 1em; 
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  .nav ul {
    display: none; 
    list-style: none;
  }

  /* .post-info-meta */
  ul.post-info-meta {
    color: #888; 
    padding: 0;
  }
  ul.post-info-meta li {
    list-style: none; 
    float: none;
  }
  ul.post-info-meta li.post-info-comment {

  }

  /* .footer */
  p.footer-copy {
    background: #000; 
    padding: 20px; 
    clear: both; 
    font-size: 0.9em; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  p.footer-copy .footer-credit {

  }

}

@media screen and (min-width: 801px) and (max-width: 980px) {

  /* Overall */
  .container {
    margin: 10px auto; 
    width: 90%; 
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .header {
    position: relative; 
    width: 90%; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
    padding: 40px 0 0 0;
  }
  .section {
    float: left; 
    width: 60%; 
    margin: 20px 0;
  }
  .aside {
    float: right; 
    width: 35%; 
    margin: 30px 0; 
    background: #f8f8f8;
  }
  .footer {
    clear: both; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
    width: 100%; 
    color: #777;
  }

  /* .header form */
  .header-form {
    clear: both; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 4px; 
    right: 20px;
  }
  .header-text {
    width: 80px; 
    border: 1px solid #bbb;
  }

  /* .nav */
  .mobile-nav {
    display: block; 
    width: 50%;
  }
  .nav {
    position: relative; 
    width: 90%; 
    display: inline-block; 
    background: #000; 
    padding: 5px 5%; 
    margin-top: 40px; 
    clear: both; 
    line-height: 1em; 
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  .nav ul {
    display: none; 
    list-style: none;
  }
  .nav a {
    display: block; 
    padding: 14px 10px; 
    color: #fff;
  }
  .nav a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline; 
    color: #fff;
  }
  .nav ul ul a {
    display: block; 
    padding: 14px; 
    position: relative;
  }

  /* .post-info-meta */
  ul.post-info-meta {
    color: #888; 
    padding: 0;
  }
  ul.post-info-meta li {
    list-style: none; 
    float: left;
  }
  ul.post-info-meta li.post-info-comment {
    float: right;
  }

  /* .footer */
  p.footer-copy {
    background: url('images/nav_bg.gif') no-repeat center; 
    padding: 10px 20px; 
    clear: both; 
    font-size: 0.9em; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  p.footer-copy .footer-credit {
    display: block; 
    float: right; 
    width: 55px; 
    height: 11px; 
    background: url('images/footer_credit.png') no-repeat 0 0; 
    text-indent: -9999px; 
    margin-top: 5px;
  }

}

@media screen and (min-width: 981px) {

  /* Overall */
  .container {
    margin: 10px auto; 
    width: 1020px; 
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .header {
    position: relative; 
    width: 1020px; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
    padding: 40px 0 0 0;
  }
  .section {
    float: left; 
    width: 640px; 
    margin: 30px 0 30px 20px;
  }
  .aside {
    float: right; 
    width: 300px; 
    margin: 30px 20px 30px 0; 
    background: #f8f8f8;
  }
  .footer {
    clear: both; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
    width: 1020px; 
    color: #777;
  }

  /* .header form */
  .header-form {
    clear: both; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 4px; 
    right: 40px;
  }
  .header-text {
    width: 100px; 
    border: 1px solid #bbb;
  }

  .header-banner {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    left: 290px;
  }

  /* .nav */
  .mobile-nav {
    display: none;
  }
  .nav {
    position: relative; 
    width: 970px; 
    display: inline-block; 
    background: #000; 
    padding: 0 25px; 
    margin-top: 40px; 
    clear: both; 
    line-height: 1em; 
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }

    .nav:before, .nav:after {
        border: 1.7em solid #000;
        content: "";
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        top: 0;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    .nav:before {
        border-left-color: #fff;
        border-right-width: 1.5em;
        left: 0;
    }
    .nav:after {
        border-left-width: 1.5em;
        border-right-color:#fff;
        right: 0;
    }

  .nav ul {
    list-style: none; 
    max-width: 780px; 
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .nav a {
    display: block; 
    padding: 14px; 
    color: #fff;
  }
  .nav a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline; 
    color: #fff;
  }
  .nav ul ul a {
    display: block; 
    padding: 14px; 
    position: relative;
  }

  /* .post-info-meta */
  ul.post-info-meta {
    color: #888; 
    padding: 0;
  }
  ul.post-info-meta li {
    list-style: none; 
    float: left;
  }
  ul.post-info-meta li.post-info-comment {
    float: right;
  }

  /* .footer */
  p.footer-copy {
    background: url('images/nav_bg.gif') no-repeat center; 
    padding: 10px 20px; 
    clear: both; 
    font-size: 0.9em; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  p.footer-copy .footer-credit {
    display: block; 
    float: right; 
    width: 55px; 
    height: 11px; 
    text-indent: -9999px; 
    margin-top: 5px;
  }

}


/* OVERALL */
body {
  font: normal 0.8em 'Muli', Lucida Sans Unicode, Lucida Grande, Verdana, Tahoma, Arial, Sans-serif; 
  color: #666; 
  background-color:#fff;
}
body p {
  margin-bottom: 20px; 
  line-height: 1.8em; 
  word-wrap: break-word; 
  -ms-word-wrap: break-word;
}

/* hgroup */
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  line-height: 1.2em; 
  margin-bottom: 15px; 
  font-family: 'Montserrat', Sans-serif; 
  font-weight: 400;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 1.6em; 
  color: #000;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 1.4em; 
  color: #000;
}
h3 {
  font-size: 1.2em; 
  color: #333;
}
h4 {
  font-size: 1.2em; 
  color: #333;
}
h5 {
  font-size: 1em; 
  color: #555;
}
h6 {
  font-size: 1em; 
  color: #555;
}

/* LINK */
a {
  color: #ff8f85; 
  text-decoration: none; 
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; 
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; 
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; 
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; 
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
a:hover {
  color: #000;
}

/* .header */
.header h1, .header h5 {
  font-size: 48px; 
  text-transform: uppercase; 
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}
.header-title {
  color: #000;
}
.header-desc {
  margin: 0; 
  color: #777;
}

/* .nav */
.nav .current-menu-item > a, .nav .current-menu-ancestor > a, .nav .current_page_item > a, .nav .current_page_ancestor > a {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.nav ul ul a {
  display: block; 
  padding: 10px; 
  position: relative;
}

.nav li {
  display: inline-block; 
  float: left; 
  position: relative; 
  z-index: 100;
}
.nav li:hover > ul {
  opacity: 1;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  zoom: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  height: auto;
}

.nav ul ul {
opacity: 0;
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
filter: alpha(opacity=0);
-webkit-transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
zoom: 0;
visibility: hidden;
height: 0;
position: absolute; width: 200px; background: #000; z-index: 200;
}

.nav ul li.has-sub > a {
  background: url('images/menu_down.gif') no-repeat right center;
}
.nav ul ul li.has-sub > a {
  background: url('images/menu_right.gif') no-repeat right center;
}

.nav ul ul li {
  display: block; 
  float: none;
}

.nav ul ul ul {
  position: absolute; 
  left: 200px; 
  top: 0;
}

/* .article */
.sticky {}
.article {
  margin-bottom: 50px; 
  padding-bottom: 20px; 
  background: url('images/break.gif') repeat-x bottom center; 
  overflow: hidden; 
  clear: both;
}
.article .post-thumb {
  padding: 2px; 
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.article .post-header {
  margin-bottom: 30px; 
  overflow: hidden;
}
.article .post-date {
  float: left; 
  margin-right: 10px; 
  background: #000; 
  color: #ddd; 
  width: 45px; 
  padding: 18px; 
  line-height: 1em; 
  font-size: 1.2em; 
  text-align: center; 
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.article .post-date span {
  color: #fff; 
  font-size: 1.4em;
}
.article h2.post-title {
  font: italic 400 1.8em 'Lora', Serif; margin: 10px 0 5px 0; 
  line-height: 1.2em;
}
.article h2.post-title a {
  color: #000;
}
.article .post-comment {
  padding: 2px 0 2px 20px; 
  background: url('images/comment_icon.gif') no-repeat 0 4px;
}
.article .attachment-alignleft {
  float: left; 
  margin: 0 10px 5px 0;
}
.article .archives {
  overflow: hidden; 
  clear: both; 
  padding: 10px 0;
}
.article .archives .archives-box {
  width: 45%; 
  float: left; 
  padding: 2px;
}

/* .article misc */
.article blockquote {
  font: italic 400 1.4em 'Lora', Serif; display: block; 
  clear: both; 
  margin: 20px 0; 
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 60px; 
  background: #f8f8f8 url('images/blockquote.gif') no-repeat 20px 25px; 
  font-style: italic; 
  color: #888;
}
.article blockquote p {
  padding: 0;
}
.article ul {
  margin: 0 0 20px 25px; 
  list-style: circle outside;
}
.article ol {
  margin: 0 0 20px 25px; 
  list-style: decimal outside;
}
.article li {
  margin: 3px 0; 
  line-height: 1.8em;
}

/* .article misc */
.pagetitle {
  text-align: center; 
  font-size: 2em; 
  padding: 20px; 
  color: #999;
}

.page-pagination {
  font-weight: bold; 
  border-top: 1px solid #eee; 
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee; 
  padding: 5px 0;
}
.page-pagination span {
  margin: 2px 5px;
}

.pagination {
  clear: both; 
  font-size: 0.85em; 
  padding: 10px 0; 
  overflow: hidden; 
  list-style: none;
}
.pagination a:hover, .pagination .current {
  padding: 5px 10px; 
  margin-right: 5px; 
  background: #ff8f85; 
  color: #fff; 
  -moz-border-radius: 4px; 
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px; 
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.pagination a {
  padding: 5px 10px; 
  margin-right: 5px; 
  background: #eee; 
  color: #666; 
  -moz-border-radius: 4px; 
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px; 
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.post-footer {
  clear: both; 
  padding: 20px 0 10px 0; 
  margin: 0; 
  overflow: hidden;
}
.post-footer ul {
  margin: 0; 
  list-style: none;
}
.post-footer ul li {
  margin: 5px 0;
}

.footer-navi {
  clear: both; 
  overflow: hidden; 
  padding: 0 !important; 
  margin-bottom: 20px; 
  border-top: 1px solid #eee; 
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}
.footer-navi li.previous {
  float: left;
}
.footer-navi li.next {
  float: right;
}

/* .gallery */
.gallery {
  clear: both; 
  overflow: hidden;
}
.gallery .gallery-item {
  margin-top: 0 !important;
}
.gallery dl {
  margin: 0;
}
.gallery a {
  padding: 5px; 
  display: block;
}
.gallery a img {
  max-width: 100%; 
  height: auto;
}
.gallery-caption {}

/* .sideform */
.sideform {
  clear: both; 
  overflow: hidden; 
  text-align: center;
}
.sidetext {
  width: 150px; 
  margin: 2px auto; 
  color: #888; 
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
}

/* .side-widget */
.side-widget {
  padding: 20px 20px 30px 20px; 
  margin-bottom: 20px; 
  background: url('images/side_bg.gif') no-repeat bottom center; 
  overflow: hidden; 
  clear: both;
}
.textwidget {
  overflow: hidden; 
  clear: both;
}
.side-widget h3 {
  font-size: 1.3em; 
  font-weight: 400; 
  text-transform: uppercase; 
  text-align: center; 
  margin-bottom: 15px; 
  color: #888;
}
.side-widget select {
  width: 90%;
}
.side-widget ol, .side-widget ul {
  clear: both; 
  list-style: none;
}
.side-widget ol.children, .side-widget ul.children {
  clear: both; 
  list-style: none; 
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.side-widget ol li, .side-widget ul li {
  margin: 5px 0; 
  line-height: 1.8em;
}

/***** WIDGET *****/
/* .flickr */
.flickr {
  clear: both; 
  padding: 10px 0;
}
.flickr .flickr_badge_image {
  float: left; 
  padding: 5px;
}
.flickr .flickr_badge_image img {}

/* .social-icons */
ul.social-icons li {
  float: left;
}
.social-rss, .social-facebook, .social-twitter, .social-pinterest {
  display: block; 
  width: 48px; 
  height: 48px; 
  float: left; 
  background: url('images/social_icons.gif') no-repeat; 
  text-indent: -9999px;
}
.social-rss {
  background-position: 0 0; 
  margin-right: 16px;
}
.social-twitter {
  background-position: -68px 0; 
  margin-right: 16px;
}
.social-facebook {
  background-position: -136px 0; 
  margin-right: 16px;
}
.social-pinterest {
  background-position: -204px 0;
}

/* .twitter */
.tweet_list {
  padding: 5px 0;
}
.tweet_time {
  font-style: italic;
}

/* .footer */
p.footer-copy a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

/* .comment-box */
.comment-box {
  padding: 0 0 20px 0; 
  overflow: hidden;
}
.comment-box h4 {
  font-size: 1.4em; 
  margin: 10px 0;
}
#respond {
  padding: 10px; 
  background: #fff;
}
.comment-text {
  width: 25%; 
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.comment-textarea {
  width: 95%;
}
.comment-text, .comment-textarea {
  border: 1px solid #ccc; 
  padding: 5px; 
  color: #999; 
  font: normal 0.85em Verdana, Tahoma, Arial, San-serif;
}
.avatar {
  margin-right: 20px; 
  float: left; 
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
.comment-meta {
  clear: both; 
  overflow: hidden;
}
.comment-meta h6 {
  font-size: 1em; 
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}
.comment-meta small {
  font-style: italic; 
  color: #999; 
  font-size: 0.85em;
}
.comment-content {
  padding: 5px 10px; 
  overflow: hidden;
}
.comment-content p {
  padding: 5px 0; 
  margin: 0 0 10px 55px; 
  line-height: 1.8em
}
.commentlist li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd; 
  margin-bottom: 20px; 
  list-style: none;
}
.commentlist li.bypostauthor {}
.commentlist ul.children {
  padding: 0;
}
.commentlist ul.children li {
  border: none; 
  border-left: 1px solid #ddd; 
  padding: 0 0 0 30px; 
  margin: 0; 
  list-style: none;
}
a.comment-reply-link {
  float: right;
}

/* #wp-calendar */
#wp-calendar {
  text-align: center; 
  width: 100%; 
  font-size: 0.9em;
}
#wp-calendar caption {
  font-weight: bold; 
  text-align: center; 
  padding: 5px 0; 
  border-top: 1px solid #eee; 
  border-left: 1px solid #eee; 
  border-right: 1px solid #eee;
}
#wp-calendar th {
  font-style: normal; 
  text-transform: capitalize; 
  padding: 2px; 
  border-right: 1px solid #eee;
}
#wp-calendar td {
  font-style: normal; 
  padding: 2px; 
  border-right: 1px solid #eee;
}
#wp-calendar tr {
  border-top: 1px solid #eee; 
  border-left: 1px solid #eee;
}
#wp-calendar tfoot td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}

/* img */
img {
  max-width: 100%; 
  height: auto;
}
img.aligncenter {
  display: block; 
  margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
}
img.alignright {
  display: inline; 
  margin: 0 0 10px 20px;
}
img.alignleft {
  display: inline; 
  margin: 0 20px 10px 0;
}
.aligncenter, .centered {
  display: block; 
  margin: auto;
}
.alignleft {
  float: left; 
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.alignright {
  float: right; 
  margin-left: 10px;
}

/* .wp-caption */
.aligncenter, div.aligncenter {
  display: block; 
  margin-left: auto; 
  margin-right: auto;
}
.wp-caption {
  border: 1px solid #ccc; 
  background: #efefef; 
  margin: 15px; 
  padding: 1%; 
  text-align: center; 
  max-width: 96%;
}
.wp-caption img {
  border: 0;
}
.wp-caption p.wp-caption-text {
  font-size: 0.85em; 
  line-height: 1.2em; 
  padding: 3px 0; 
  margin: 0;
}

/* Input and label */
select, textarea, input {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  color: #888;
  padding: 5px; 
  -moz-border-radius: 5px; 
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
  border-radius: 5px; 
  font-family: 'Muli', Arial, Verdana, Sans-serif;
}
input[type=submit] {
  border: 1px solid #ccc; 
  color: #555; 
  cursor: pointer; 
  background: #eee; 
  padding: 5px 10px; 
  -moz-border-radius: 3px; 
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px; 
  border-radius: 3px; 
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; 
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; 
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; 
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; 
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
input[type=submit]:hover {
  border: 1px solid #aaa; 
  background: #ccc;
}
label {
  display: inline-block; 
  margin-right: 20px;
}

/* Misc */
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
.focused {
  border: 1px solid #888;
}
.highlight {
  background: #efefef; 
  padding: 0 2px;
}
.button {
  padding: 1px 5px;
}
.fade {
  filter: alpha(opacity=50); 
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.clearfix {
  clear: both; 
  height: 10px;
}
.shadow {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 #aaa; 
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 #aaa;
}
.transparency {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}
.radius-100 {
  -moz-border-radius: 100px; 
  -webkit-border-radius: 100px; 
  border-radius: 100px;
}
.radius-10 {
  -moz-border-radius: 10px; 
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px; 
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.radius-8 {
  -moz-border-radius: 8px; 
  -webkit-border-radius: 8px; 
  border-radius: 8px;
}
.radius-4 {
  -moz-border-radius: 4px; 
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px; 
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is line 270 in the css doc

```
.nav:before, .nav:after {
    border: 1.7em solid #000000;
    bottom: 0;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

This is what you're looking for :) It's the border that creates that effect. Hope this helps!

Comment: Yep that did the job. I removed this along with what Michal Chovanec said and it's gone now. Kind of odd though cause both of your answers are correct and I don't know which one to mark now :(

Comment: Up vote the other answer as we're both right, it should give us similar scores :) I've up voted his too

Answer (score 1):

You can find it in "stylesheet.css" line 279:

```
.nav:before {
    border-left-color: #fff;
    border-right-width: 1.5em;
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Ah I must've missed that, thanks a lot! :) Just a bit of a follow up question then. I fixed it now by making the color #000 and that works fine but I'm sure that's not the 'correct' way to do it. If i just remove the whole .nav:before then it kinda messes the whole thing up.